# In Tcl code, can I append and sort a list while I am iterating over it in foreach

Tags: list, foreach, tcl

I have sorted list in tcl and i am iterating over it using foreach
During iteration i wish to append an item to the list and also make sure that item goes at the right place in the sorting order.
Something like this:

```
foreach item $mylist {
 ..
   if { $sun == "shining" } { 
     set mylist [lsort [lappend mylist "newitem"]] 
     continue
   }
 ..
 }
```

Is it a valid thing in tcl. Will this work as expected under all cases & circumstances?

Comment: First of all, your argument order for `lappend` is wrong. It should be the list var first followed by newitem. Second, the thing you pass to lappend is your list variable's name. So you need to remove the `$` - `lappend mylist newitem` (no $)

Comment: Also, sorting after each append is very inefficient. You can achieve the same result if you sort after `foreach` and you only need to sort (an expensive operation) once.

Comment: Those were typos.. fixed them.  I cant sort after foreach as foreach itself is where the utility of mylist is. Whatever new item i am adding "while iterating" should appear in the right (sorted) order. Will that happen with the above code always?

Comment: `foreach` logically takes a copy of the list it is iterating over; you can manipulate the list, but the iterations will be done over the list as it was before it was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach` will expand the `$mylist` variable *once*, before starting to iterate:

```
% set mylist {1 2 3 4 5}
1 2 3 4 5
% foreach item $mylist { puts $item; lappend mylist "$item$item" }
1
2
3
4
5
% set mylist
1 2 3 4 5 11 22 33 44 55
```

So, it depends on what you expect when you say "does it work as expected"

Comment: Thanks. My question was - whether it will also iterate over the elements which are being appended within the foreach loop. Guess the answer is - it will NOT.

Comment: If you want that, you probably need a `while true {...}` loop with a `break` condition. But it's a fundamental question: if you change the order of the list while iterating over it, what's the _next_ element?

Comment: Agree with your question. I guess the possible answer could be - the element which comes _next_ to the _current_ element in the _latest order_ at the time of next iteration.

Comment: Implementing that will be slow and error-prone: you'd have to seek through the list for every iteration instead of keeping a pointer into the list. And what about duplicate elements: which one is current?

Answer (score 0):

As glenn suggested, you can use a `while` whose test condition is expressed over the state of the list (e.g. using `llength`).

```
set mylist {1 2 3 4 5}

while {[llength $mylist]} {
    # consume first list element
    set mylist [lassign $mylist item]
    if {$item <= 5} {
      lappend mylist $item$item
    }
}
```

Note that `lassign` turns out useful to consume the list. It goes without saying, still saying, that you need some stop condition (e.g., the list must deplete at some point, or you `break` explicitly).

Comment: Interesting to note about `lassign` to consume the list in `while`  loop